# Why isn't if condition to check if a hash[key] is set to a value of true (boolean) isn't working as expected?

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

I have the following nested hash called cars

```
{:honda=>{year=>2008,is_condition_good?=>true},
 :toyota=>{year=>2010,is_condition_good?=>false}
}
```

I want to return the nested hash that satisfy `is_condition_good? = true`. I realize I can use select method `cars.select {|car, attributes| attributes[:is_condition_good?]=true}` but the following code seems like it should work as well but for some reason, it doesn't get into the if statement loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
cars.each do |car, attributes|
  if attributes[:is_condition_good?] == true then
     return attributes
  end
end
```

I printed `attributes[:is_condition_good?]` before `cars.each do |car, attributes|` to see that it printed either `true` or `false` and it did.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example? `cars` is never assigned and there’s a `return` without a method. Your initial hash also isn’t valid.

Answer (score 7):

You propose to write:

```
cars = {
  :honda =>{ year => 2008, is_condition_good? => true },
  :toyota=>{ year => 2010, is_condition_good? => false }
}
```

How will Ruby parse this when she gets to `year` (which is neither a string nor a symbol). She will conclude that it must be the name of a variable or a method. When she discovers there is no variable or method by that name she will raise an exception.

Similarly, had Ruby not already raised an exception when parsing `find`, `is_condition_good?` would present the same issue, though, because of the question mark, it could not be a variable.

I expect you intend both of those to be symbols, in which case you should write:

```
cars = {
  :honda  => { :year => 2008, :is_condition_good? => true },
  :toyota => { :year => 2010, :is_condition_good? => false }
}
```

which alternatively can be expressed (your choice):

```
cars = {
  :honda  => { year: 2008, condition_good?: true },
  :toyota => { year: 2010, condition_good?: false }
}
```

or

```
cars = {
  honda:  { year: 2008, condition_good?: true },
  toyota: { year: 2010, condition_good?: false }
}
```

---

Now consider your "looping" code:

```
def doit(cars)
  cars.each do |car, attributes|
    puts "car = #{car}, attributes = #{attributes}"
    if attributes[:condition_good?] == true then
      return attributes
    end
  end
end
```

I've put your (modified) code in a method because it contains a `return` statement and one returns from methods. I've also added a `puts` statement (to be removed later) to display the values of the block variables.

Note that this method will return as soon as a car in good condition is found. By contrast, using `select` (which you mentioned), would return an array with one element for each car in good condition.

Now let's execute `doit`:

```
doit(cars) 
  #=> {:year=>2008, :condition_good?=>true}
```

This displays:

```
car = honda, attributes = {:year=>2008, :condition_good?=>true}
```

Had there been no car having a good condition `nil` would be have been returned.

---

You could improve your code by using the method [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

```
def doit(cars)
  cars.find do |car, attributes|
    attributes[:condition_good?]
  end
end
```

Notice this does not require a `return` statement.

Since `attributes[:condition_good?]` returns `true` or `false`, it's the same as:

```
attributes[:condition_good?] == true
```

We should drop the `== true` lest other Rubiests might snicker behind our backs in the belief that we were unaware that `== true` was superfluous.

We now obtain:

```
doit cars
  #=> [:honda, {:year=>2008, :condition_good?=>true}]
```

Hold the phone! That returned the key and value for which the value `:condition_good` is `true`. We just want the value, so we need to write:

```
def doit(cars)
  cars.find do |car, attributes|
    attributes[:condition_good?]
  end.last
end
```

```
doit cars
  #=> {:year=>2008, :condition_good?=>true}
```

Here `.last` pulls out the last element of

```
[:honda, {:year=>2008, :condition_good?=>true}]
```

If you are thinking that's a little ugly you would not be alone.

---

There are many ways to organize these calculations. I might do it as follows.

```
def doit(cars)
  cars.each_key.find { |name| cars[name][:condition_good?] }
end
```

```
car = doit(cars)
  #=> :honda
```

At this point, I can extract whatever information I need from:

```
attributes = cars[:honda]
  #=> {:year=>2008, :condition_good?=>true}
```

See [Hash#each_key](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-each_key).

Comment: @engineersmnky made an observation in a (subsequently removed) comment that raised an interesting issue. It turns out that `{:condition_good? =>true}` evaluates correctly but `{:condition_good?=>true}` raises the exception `SyntaxError: <main>: syntax error, unexpected =>)`. I would be interested if knowing if this behaviour is expected or if it indicates a bug in Ruby (v2.7.1).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It makes sense now. I tried your suggestions and they work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
cars = {:honda=>{year=>2008,is_condition_good?=>true},
 :toyota=>{year=>2010,is_condition_good?=>false}
}

cars.each do |car, attributes|
  if attributes[:is_condition_good?]
    return attributes
  end
end
```

OR

```
cars.select { |car, attributes| attributes[:is_condition_good?] }
```